# Internal traffic between two Google Cloud Compute instances not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to enable internal traffic between two VM instances in the same VPC **but** block traffic from outside the VPC.

I've set up a new VPC network named vpc-dev.

In this network, I've created two VM instances with Ubuntu 20.04.

I've created a new rule for allowing internal traffic in this VPC with the instructions from google cloud docs: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls.

But when I do - *curl 10.0.3.9*  -> I'm getting - *curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.3.9 port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused*

The configuration of the VPC for the selected region:

[image]

The VM instances:
[image]

Comment: Are you certain there is no firewall enabled on the Ububtu VMs ?

Comment: Are you sure that something is listening on port80 on the target vm? If so, is it exposed on 0.0.0.0 IP address

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I can't believe it was this simple... I thought its working like ping in windows(I'm new on Linux).
Once I run a docker container to listen on port 80 it worked. Thank you guys! :)